# How to Prepare a 80mL Carbonic Acid-Bicarbonate buffer solution of ph=7.4 in laboratory?

Tags: acid-base, experimental-chemistry, ph, titration

I have the following materials which I can use:

- 0.1 M sodium bicarbonate solution
- Sodium Bicarbonate powder
- 0.1 M HCL
- Distilled Water
- Universal Indicator

It will be a great help if you can provide with step by step instructions on preparing this 80 ml Buffer solution at an exact ph of 7.4.

Kind Regards,